# About handling white space in sys.argv in Python

Tags: python, powershell

I don't understand how python handles whites in sys.argv.

Prepare the following Python code.

```py
import sys

args = sys.argv
print(args)
```

Define a variable that stores JSON using here documents in powershell.

```
PS C:\devspace\python\test> $json = @'
>> {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
>> '@.Replace('"','\"')
PS C:\devspace\python\test> echo $json
{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}
```

Give the json variable to the parameter and execute.
As the execution result shows, 「'{" key1 ":" value1 "," key2 ":" value2 "}'」 is interpreted as one parameter.

```
PS C:\devspace\python\test> python .\test.py -input $json
['.\\test.py', '-input', '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}']
```

However, it inserts a blank anywhere in the JSON.
Below we will insert a space between 「key2」.

```
PS C:\devspace\python\test> $json = @'
>> {"key1":"value1","ke y2":"value2"}
>> '@.Replace('"','\"')
PS C:\devspace\python\test> echo $json
{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"ke y2\":\"value2\"}
```

Run again.
Then, the value stored in the json variable will be interpreted as two parameters, 「'{"key1":"value1","ke'」,「 'y2":"value2"}'」.

```
PS C:\devspace\python\test> python .\test.py -input $json
['.\\test.py', '-input', '{"key1":"value1","ke', 'y2":"value2"}']
```

I want it to be interpreted as 「'{" key1 ":" value1 "," ke y2 ":" value2 "}'」 when inserting a blank.
How can I do that?

I'm using python 3.8.0 and powershell 5.1.
The execution result of the $PSVersionTable is as follows.

```
PS C:\devspace\python\test> python --version
Python 3.8.0

PS C:\devspace\python\test> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1237
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1237
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: In linux you would do `python test.py -input '$json'
But I dont know if it works in windows.

Comment: Also you could join all the args after `-input'. Not very elegant, but works

Comment: If I try your code, which looks correct, I get the expected behavior. Is there another factor at play that isn't currently shown in the question?

Comment: Try `.Replace('"','""')`